# Convexity adjustment for inflation

Tags: hullwhite, convexity

I'd like to prove the following equation:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{e^{\int_0^{T_1} y_s d s}}{e^{\int_0^{T_2} r_s d s}}\right]=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\int_0^{T_2} r_s d s}\right]}{\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\int_0^{T_1} y_s d s}\right]} e^{-\operatorname{COV}\left(\int_0^{T_2} r_s d s,\: \int_0^{T_1} y_s d s\right)+\operatorname{Var}\left(\int_0^{T_1} y_s d s\right)}$

where *y* and *r* are two correlated H&W processes and $T_1 \le T_2$.

Comment: I rewrote the equation in the picture using MathJax. Pls feel free to modify if and when the changes I made are approved. Mentioning the exact source for the equation and any work you have done so far might help in getting a better answer.

Comment: Thank you Alper, it's an internal result and I could not find the proof...

Comment: As written, the statement doesn’t appear to be true when both processes tend to a non stochastic limit.

Comment: This is the result used in the production. The variance part in the adjustment part looks weird to me though, if there's no correlation between r and y, one should just have the ZC terms on the right-hand side

Comment: tried 3 or 4 times, but my result is missing the Var of integral in the exponential part. checking in the library if they indeed use this formula in production. so weired